# VSCode QuickPick button is misaligned

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a VSC extension that uses QuickPick with a button.

Here's how I create a QuickPick:

```ts
import {
  window,
  QuickInputButton,
  ThemeIcon,
} from "vscode";
//...
const qp = window.createQuickPick();
//...
qp.buttons = [addButton];
//...
qp.show();
```

and here's `addButton`

```ts
const addButton: QuickInputButton = {
  iconPath: new ThemeIcon("add"),
  tooltip: "tooltip",
};
```

When I run extension, the 'add' button is not centered vertically:

[image]

That shouldn't happen? How can I make it centered?

Comment: You don't have control over this as an extension author. You could try reporting it as a bug on the VSCode issue tracker.